# Why are these 2 functions different?

Tags: r

```
strrev =

        function(x)
        paste(substring(x,nchar(x):1,nchar(x):1), collapse = "")
```

vs

```
strrev <- function(x)
          {paste(substring(x,nchar(x):1,nchar(x):1), collapse = "")
          }
```

Why do both ways work? Are the curly braces not mandatory when defining a function?
I'm new to R so please go easy on me :(

Comment: R allows one-line functions without the braces. Similarly you can do a one-line if statement without the braces. It's just a shorthand for the same thing when you don't need multiple lines

Answer (score 1):

The functions are totally identical as far as `R` is concerned.

```
strrev = function(x)
         paste(substring(x,nchar(x):1,nchar(x):1), collapse = "")
strrev(1)
# [1] "1"

strrev <- function(x) {
            paste(substring(x,nchar(x):1,nchar(x):1), collapse = "")
          }
strrev(1)
# [1] "1"
```

By default, `function` will read the first line (or whatever is in the curly brackets) and return the last line.

For example, in this case, if we add a line without the curly brackets, only the first line is passed to the function, the second one is just executed:

```
strrev = function(x)
         paste(substring(x,nchar(x):1,nchar(x):1), collapse = "")
         print("do something else")
# [1] "do something else"         
strrev(1)
# [1] "1"
```

We can thus isolate all that with the curly brackets

```
strrev <- function(x) {
            paste(substring(x,nchar(x):1,nchar(x):1), collapse = "")
            print("do something else")
          }
strrev(1)
#[1] "do something else"
```

However, although the first line (`paste(...)`) is executed within the function, only the last line (`print(...)`) is returned. To actually do both, you can use `return()` within the function. Note that the execution exits the function at `return`. In this example, the last `print()` is not executed.

```
strrev <- function(x) {
            y <- paste(substring(x,nchar(x):1,nchar(x):1), collapse = "")
            print("do something else")
            return(y)
            print("execution already exit!")
          }
strrev(1)
#[1] "do something else"
#[1] "1"
```

As a "good practice" advice, the latest format is always the best one (i.e. you know what is executed and what is returned).